# Paypal Pay Now link not working

Tags: paypal

I have an auction site and after auction end I want to send the Paypal high bidders an email with a Paypal Pay Now link. As the amount and the item reference must be variable, I cannot use the "hosted Paypal button".

This Paypal link has worked in maybe 80% of all cases. But the rest of 20% does not work according to the feedback from my clients. It has even not worked for the same client in the USA for whom it worked one week before. From one feedback from a client in Portugal I know that the amount format was refused by Paypal. But I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Here is a link example:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&lc=US&business=xxxx@mydomain.com&item_name=Order+No%2E+25376&amount=72.00&currency_code=USD&notify_url=xxxx@mydomain.com

Testing with the sandbox works fine for this link. But the real thing does not, and the errors drive my clients and me nuts. What is wrong with this code. Please help.

Comment: "Not working" does nothing for us to try and help you.  I clicked the link you provided here, and even though it's got a bogus email included, it redirected to PayPal and asked me for login just fine, so it seems to be working as expected from what I can see.  You mentioned "the errors drive my clients and me nuts" but what is the error?

Comment: Hi Andrew - Thanks for replying. ´My clients are elderly art collectors and it is difficult to get an error code back from them. But last night I got one - for precisely this link with this amount and this item_name. It is "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount"

Comment: The same link but with different amounts and item names worked for 2 other clients in the US the very same day. That's so strange. And I myself cannot reproduce it. It works for me too. But I have no reasons to doubt the error feedbacks from my clients. Something must be wrong. It just looks as if the link is handled by different Paypal software versions.

Comment: Ok, well the error is pretty straight forward.  Now we need to see the request string that resulted in that error.  There must be something wrong with the amount format.